# Which is better to use for serialization objects? JsonSerializer or JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json-deserialization, jsonserializer

I want to serialize object in c# and learn that we can do this both `JsonSerializer` and `JsonConvert`. I know about documentation knowledges about these.

But I want to know which is better to use for `serialization` objects? `JsonSerializer` or `JsonConvert`?

Comment: And your question is...? Can you provide some sort of context? Completely unclear what you're asking...

Comment: now you understand that question?

Comment: This question is unfortunately off-topic due to the site policy of not allowing questions which ask for recommendations. The term "better" is subjective and prone to being opinion-based, something which is also off-topic. Without a much clearer question both the question and potential answers is going to be off-topic for this site. If you can reword it it may be on-topic. A tip would be to simply test both, or at least one of them and if you encounter something that doesn't work come back and ask about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JsonConvert` from `JSON.net` is reportedly better for performance. I actually use it myself and find it very easy to use and works well with `attributes` in `classes`. In terms of memory usages it was good for us. The application I work is able to handle around 3500 to 4000 requests including 3 `deserialization`, 2 `http service` calls to retrieve data and, one `serialization` and one service call to push data.. So, in terms of performance it was a great choice.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/performance.htm (I know, a bit biased, but still)
nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Comment: I've also got some "circular reference" errors when using JsonSerializer with some structs, while JsonConvert handles them successfully without extra effort.

Answer (score -2):

"***JsonConvert***" is good for Small Project but for more than 4000 request and big Project with massiv Data, become "**Memory out of exception**" Error!!

then you have to use "***JsonSerializer*** "